# How do I add storage with cloud templating?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template to spin up an EC2 instance.

```
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Type: String
    Description: Instance type for RStudio. Default is t2.micro.
    AllowedValues:
      - t2.micro
      - t2.small
      - t2.medium
      - t2.large
    ConstraintDescription: 'Valid instance type in the t2 family'
    Default: t2.micro
  ImageId:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Image::Id'
    Description: >-
      Amazon Linux Image ID. Default is for 2017.03.01 (HVM). N.B. 
    Default: ami-4fffc834
```

When I spin up the instance manually, there is an option to add storage. It defaults to 8gb and I'd like to do 16gb instead.

I looked for the syntax to add storage with CloudFormation. What is the syntax to set a volume size other than the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Block Device Mapping for that like this...

```
 "BlockDeviceMappings": [
    {
      "DeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
      "Ebs": {
        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
        "VolumeType": "standard",
        "VolumeSize": 16
      }
    }
  ]
```

A working example can be found here...

https://github.com/shantanuo/cloudformation/blob/master/security.template2.txt

Comment: Another example can be found here... https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/EC2/EC2_Instance_With_Ephemeral_Drives.yaml